# Find out when core dump is finished

Tags: linux, bash, coredump

I am working on a bash script that collects various diagnostic information on a CentOS server and packages them up so that they can be sent to our company for analysis. As part of this script, I check to see if the company's application is responsive. If it is not, I trigger a core dump of the application process:

```
kill -6 $app_pid
```

This command will cause a process core dump to be written for the pid `$app_pid`. However, I need a way to wait until the core dump generation is finished. Otherwise, I can create corrupt diagnostics packages due to the incomplete core dump.

I am hoping to do this check using the default centos packages but am also open to installing additional packages if I must.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a StackOverflow question more than a [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) question. It's about making a determination that certainly can be pertinent when writing code, but is by no means **only** relevant in that situation -- a sysadmin trying to make a manual determination could have the same question.

Comment: BTW -- which version of CentOS, exactly? If you're systemd-based, then you have `systemd-coredump` available.

Comment: We are still using CentOS 6 for our application servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get my script to wait for the core dump write to finish by using `inotifywait`. See the following snippet:

```
core_file="core.$app_pid"
core_path=/path/core/file/dir
core_complete="false"
# Setup inotifywait loop to wait until core file has been complety written
inotifywait -e close_write --format '%f' $core_path | while read line; do
  echo "File $line was closed"
  # Check to see if the line we read was the core file
  if [[ "$line" == "$core_file"  ]]; then
    echo "Core file write complete"
    core_complete="true"
  fi
done
```

This so far has seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism that gives you the most control is to specify a pipeline in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. This will let a program of your choosing be executed when a coredump is created, so that program can be 100% certain that it has the full dump when (and only when!) its stdin file descriptor is in the EOF condition. See the section "Piping core dumps to a program" in [`man 5 core`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html).

If you're using systemd (as modern versions of CentOS do), the `systemd-coredump` program will already configure itself in this way.  `systemd-coredump` renames files from a temporary name when compression is complete, so it already does the work of ensuring that you only have a complete coredump ready to log.

Thus, if you have a file named of the form:

```
/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.*.lz4
```

(or otherwise with the extension of your chosen compression algorithm), you can already be assured that it's complete, as that file was written and had its permissions set *before* it was renamed to that final name.